# FileUpload with HtmlUnit doesn't fire fileUploadListener-Event (Primefaces auto upload)

Tags: selenium, file-upload, primefaces, webdriver, htmlunit

I'm trying to automate a file-upload with WebDriver. It works fine for ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver, but refuses to work for HTMLUnit.

I've already read

[Using Webdriver for PrimeFaces file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380058/using-webdriver-for-primefaces-file-upload)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753497/unable-to-automate-filling-of-form-with-file-upload-using-htmlunit

[Unable to upload file using Selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757746/unable-to-upload-file-using-selenium-web-driver)

but both were not helpfull.

The selenium (java)code for this upload-action is quiete simple:

```
String elementXPath = "//input[contains(@id,'FileUpload_input')]";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXPath));
element.sendKeys(pathToFile);
```

The html-code of the inputElement is:

```
<div class="fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
    <label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left fileinput-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
        <input type="file" id="form:FileUpload_input" name="form:FileUpload_input">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="fileupload-content ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <table class="files"></table>
</div>
```

maybe necessary, the primefaces-codesnippet of the input-Element:

```
<div class="#{modalDialog ? 'span5' : 'span6'}">
    <p:fileUpload id="FileUpload" mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="2097152" fileUploadListener="#{ClassView.handleFileUpload}"
    label="Upload" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|GIF|jpe?g|JPE?G|png|PNG)$/" process="@this"
    showButtons="false"/>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's a picure-Upload. The noteworthy characteristic of this upload is, that there is no 'confirm'- or 'submit'-button.

The testautomation works fine for the main-browsers, but fails with htmlUnit. After hours of debugging, I can confirm, that htmlUnit performs the 'sendKeys'-Methode, but this doesn't trigger the fileUploadListener. I already tried to click other Elements, so there is a focusLost-Action, but that didn't help.
Indeed, a 'driver.getPageSource()' after the 'sendKeys' delivers:

```
<div class="fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
    <label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left fileinput-button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
        <input id="form:FileUpload_input" name="form:FileUpload_input" value="correct\path\to\file\pic.png" type="file" >
    </label>
</div>
<div class="fileupload-content ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <table class="files">
        <tbody align="left">
            <tr class="template-upload" style="">
                <td class="preview"></td>
                <td class="name">pic.png</td>
                <td class="size"></td>
                <td class="progress">
                    <div class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="100">
                        <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%; display: block;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="start">
                    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-state-hover" type="submit">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n"></span>
                        <span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td class="cancel">
                    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"></span>
                        <span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So there are now buttons...why?
I still tried to click the button with xPath `"//td[@class='start']//button"` but still nothing happend. No Fileupload.

HtmlDriver has javascript enabled and also I'm using NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController(). I already tried waiting for over 30 Seconds but still that doesn't work.

Is there someoone who knows this problem and it's solution...or at least a workaround?

Comment: A showcase for this Upload-WebElement can be found here: http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
I was still using selenium 2.40, upgrading to 2.42 solved the problem although the changelog didn't suggested a possible bugfix for my problem.